# Warpinator and UFW

Tags: ufw

I have UFW set up to accept traffic across Port 42000, which is what Warpinator is using.  Is there a way I can restrict that further to only computers on the internal network instead of leaving that port wide open to the world at large?

Comment: With my router, the port will be open to computers on the local network only - because there's no port forwarding enabled on the router. So, I can access kgiii-desktop.local:42000 locally but my-public-ip:42000 doesn't do anything at all. If the port isn't open and forwarding at the router, you may not need to worry about that at all. It's still a valid question, but you may not need to bother. You can find various tools to do a port scan of your public IP address to check this sort of thing.

Comment: My router defines my particular PC as the "DMZ" so it is wide open to the internet.  That's why I've set up ufw on the PC itself.

Comment: Yeah, I could see why you'd want that. I'm pretty glad mine requires manual intervention to enable port forwarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up UFW rules like that. For example, these rules allow access to port 22 only from my LAN and VPN. (the default is DENY)

```
22                         ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24            
22                         ALLOW       10.8.0.0/24
```

Reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands